# Selenium Programming -- Pressed F12, now how to copy paste Code from Chrome?

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, selenium

I pressed F12 in Chrome, and I can see my code.
How do I copy the code.  (see screenshot)
I am able to press ellipses on the left, select Copy, then select Copy Element.
It copies into buffer and I can paste from it.
But whatever I get is not well formatted.
If I want to be able to ask a question on the board about something, this sort of paste would be very unfriendly for the person wanting to answer the question.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJGA5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I have found it to save as xml and attach.
You can also take screenshots of html code when you post question to board.
Reason is that nobody really modifies the source code of the website.

Answer (score 0):

For best results in copying HTML code from a website, I recommend using the free version of [CoffeCup HTML editor](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/)

**EDIT:** A better way to do this within Chrome itself is to put "view-source:" before the website name. Example: `view-source:http://example.com`. It is formatted the way the website wrote it.

Comment: I downloaded the free version.  I paste in the code.  It is still not formatted nicely.  Is there a way to make it format in a nice way?

Comment: I am making some progress.  If I save as XML it is openable in a user friendly format.... But I want to be able to share that in a nice way on a board.... copy paste from that doesn't have it nicely tabbed.  i may just attach the xml on the board....

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the first or second line  that will bring you the whole html. The exact line is

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>...`

Try to copy outerHTML. I don't know if this works or is what you want.